# Derivative of inverse function proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, proof-verification, continuity

Can someone verify whether my attempt to prove this theorem is correct?

Notice that I use a generalized definition of derivative:

Let $f: E \subseteq \mathbb{R}  \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Let $p$ both a point and a limit point of $E$. Then we define the derivative of $f$ at $p$ as the limit $f'(p) = \lim_{x \to p, x \in E \setminus \{p\}} \frac{f(x)-f(p)}{x-p}$, provided the limit exists.

> **Theorem**: Let $f: E \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to F \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an invertible function that is differentiable at $p \in
>  E$. Suppose that $f^{-1}: F \to E$ is continuous at $f(p)$ and that
>   $f'(p) \neq 0$. Then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $f(p)$, and we have
>
> $$(f^{-1})'(f(p)) = \frac{1}{f'(p)}$$

**Proof**: Before proving the theorem, we have to check that differentiation at $f(p)$ makes sense: we have to show that $f(p)$ is a limit point of $Y$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Because $f$ is differentiable at $p$, $f$ is continuous at $p$ and it follows that $|f(p)-f(x)| < \epsilon$ whenever $x \in (p- \delta, p + \delta) \cap E \setminus \{p\}$ for some $\delta > 0$. Notice: $f'(p) \neq 0$ implies that $f$ is not constant on $(p- \delta, p + \delta) \cap E \setminus \{p\}$ (if it were constant, we would have $f'(p) = \lim_{x \to p} \frac{f(x)-f(p)}{x-p} = \lim_{x \to p, x \in E \cap (p- \delta, p + \delta)\setminus \{p\}}\frac{f(x)-f(p)}{x-p} = 0)$. Combining these facts, we deduce that $0 < |f(x)-f(p)| < \epsilon$ for some $x \in E$, and $f(p)$ is a limit point of $F = f(E)$.

Define $$F: E \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \begin{cases} \frac{f(x)-f(p)}{x-p} \quad x \neq p \\ f'(p) \quad x = p\end{cases}$$

Clearly, $F$ is continuous at $p$.

The theorem now follows from the following easy calculation:

$$(f^{-1})'(f(p)) = \lim_{y \to f(p)} \frac{f^{-1}(y)- f^{-1}(f(p))}{y-f(p)}$$

$$= \lim_{y \to f(p)}\frac{1}{\frac{f(f^{-1}(y))-f(p)}{f^{-1}(y)- p}}$$

$$ = \lim_{y \to f(p)} \frac{1}{F(f^{-1}(y))}$$

$$=  \frac{1}{F( \lim_{y \to f(p)} f^{-1}(y))} =  \frac{1}{F(p)} = \frac{1}{f'(p)}$$

However, some equalities need some explanation. The second equality is justified by noticing that $f^{-1}(y) - p = f^{-1}(y) - f^{-1}(f(p))$ is zero only when $y = f(p)$, so there are no trouble with dividing by zero. The fourth equality uses the continuity of $F$ at $p$ and the fifth equality follows from the continuity of $f^{-1}$ at $f(p) \quad \square$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks fine to me with one exception. You don't want to claim that $f$ isn't constant on $(p-\delta,p+\delta)$. You want to claim that $f(x)\ne f(p)$ for all $x$ with $0<|x-p|<\delta$. (The proof for that is not quite the proof you've supplied.) You need this because you need to know that as $y\to f(p)$ you can make sense of the inverse function (and you never have a division by zero problem). In some sense, the statement of your theorem is flawed, as you're assuming existence of the inverse function. That should be part of what you *prove* here — namely, that $f$ is one-to-one on some interval around $p$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It made me realise that the constant part needs modification. I don't really get what's wrong with the theorem statement though. It's completely similar to Tao's statement about this theorem in his analysis book, but he provides another proof.

Comment: The whole point (and, even more importantly so in multivariable) is to have a sufficient condition to be guaranteed an inverse function (locally). [When you get to multivariable analysis/calculus, you might find my YouTube lectures of interest. They're linked in my profile.]

Comment: Can't we just, if an inverse function locally exist, restrict the domain and then apply this theorem?

Comment: But you don't want to assume it. You want to know that if $f'(p)\ne 0$, then you're guaranteed to have an inverse function on an interval around $p$ ... plus continuity, differentiability, and the formula for the derivative.

Comment: The problem here is first that my domain isn't necessarily an interval. But let's assume for a moment it is. The condition $f'(p) \neq 0$ should imply that we locally have an inverse? Is there an easy proof? I can see that if we have $f'(p) \neq 0$ in a nbh, we can use IVT for derivatives to show that $f$ is monotonic on a nbh and hence invertible. But is this true?

Comment: Things like Rolle's Theorem and the IVT for derivatives are based on intervals. But you should be able to prove that if $f'(p)\ne 0$ (with your generality) there is a $\delta$ so that $f(x)\ne f(p)$ for $x\in E$ and $0<|x-p|<\delta$. Do you see why?

Comment: Ah yes that's not hard actually. The difference quotient must be non zero in a nbh of p, meaning that the numerator must be non zero and we are done. Is that correct?

Comment: Yup. Now start fixing your write-up :)

Comment: It's certainly no waste to reward a user that has helped me greatly :)

Comment: Please don't waste your points on me. :) Just keep learning well.

Comment: @Math_QED : You write "Tao's statement about this theorem in his analysis book."  Please provide a full bibliographical citation for the interested reader

Comment: It's in Tao's analysis: volume 1 chapter of differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

Your work will be done faster if not make use of the First Principle of Derivative.

We know that $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$, differentiate it combining with Chain Derivative, we have  $$\begin{align}(f^{-1}(f(x)))'&=1\\f^{-1}{'}(f(x))f'(x)&=1\\\therefore f^{-1}{'}(f(x))&=\dfrac1{f'(x)}\end{align}$$

I am not too used in rigorous proof in derivative (such like the first principle) but I think your proof is good enough.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think you can't use the chain rule, otherwise you assume that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $f(x)$ (and this is to be proven).

Comment: Yes, this is the typical "sloppy" plug-and-chug derivation one finds in some calculus books. But it indeed assumes the main issue — that the inverse function is differentiable in the first place.